# Cumulative product grouped by given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 21, 20, 1.10],
                   [1, 22, float('NaN'), 1.10], 
                   [1, 23, float('NaN'), 1.12], 
                   [2, 21, 15, 1.30],
                   [2, 22, float('NaN'), 1.12],
                   [3, 21, 25, 1.15], 
                   [3, 22, float('NaN'), 1.00],
                   [3, 23, float('NaN'), 1.13]], columns=['User', 'Age', 'Salary', 'Rate'])

╔══════╦═════╦════════╦══════╗
║ User ║ Age ║ Salary ║ Rate ║
╠══════╬═════╬════════╬══════╣
║    1 ║  21 ║ 20     ║ 1.10 ║
║    1 ║  22 ║ NaN    ║ 1.10 ║
║    1 ║  23 ║ NaN    ║ 1.12 ║
║    2 ║  21 ║ 15     ║ 1.30 ║
║    2 ║  22 ║ NaN    ║ 1.12 ║
║    3 ║  21 ║ 25     ║ 1.15 ║
║    3 ║  22 ║ NaN    ║ 1.00 ║
║    3 ║  23 ║ NaN    ║ 1.13 ║
╚══════╩═════╩════════╩══════╝
```

I need to get the cumulative product for every missing value in Salary column, as follows:

```
╔══════╦═════╦════════╦══════╗
║ User ║ Age ║ Salary ║ Rate ║
╠══════╬═════╬════════╬══════╣
║    1 ║  21 ║ 20     ║ 1.10 ║
║    1 ║  22 ║ 22     ║ 1.10 ║
║    1 ║  23 ║ 24.2   ║ 1.12 ║
║    2 ║  21 ║ 15     ║ 1.30 ║
║    2 ║  22 ║ 19.5   ║ 1.12 ║
║    3 ║  21 ║ 25     ║ 1.15 ║
║    3 ║  22 ║ 28.75  ║ 1.00 ║
║    3 ║  23 ║ 28.75  ║ 1.13 ║
╚══════╩═════╩════════╩══════╝
```

I have tried severals options, for example:

```
df.groupby('User')['Rate'].cumprod().mul('Salary')
```

But none of those worked. Is there a way to avoid a for loop?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first Salary is always Non-null, you can `ffill` it. Also, based on your output, it appears you need to shift the cumsum down by 1 row before multiplying.

```
(df.groupby('User')['Rate']
   .apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().shift())
   .mul(df['Salary'].ffill())
   .fillna(df['Salary']))

0    20.00
1    22.00
2    24.20
3    15.00
4    19.50
5    25.00
6    28.75
7    28.75
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Oh my.. I was so close!! Thank you!

Comment: @Snedecor The result is different from that portrayed in your question, so please cross check the math is correct, thank you :-)

Comment: done! I edited my question because I've made some changes previously and forgot to edit the code.

Comment: @Snedecor There is still some difference, one of us must be incorrect ;)

Comment: Also, for those interested, I added a few extra lines in order to acchieve the exact output posted. df['Salary_'] = df.groupby('User')['Rate'].cumprod().mul(df['Salary'].ffill()).shift() and then df[~df['Salary'].isna(), 'Salary_'] = df[~df['Salary'].isna(), 'Salary']. @cs95 could you add this to your answer!? Thank you!

Comment: @Snedecor Ah I understand you needed to shift the cumprod down by one, please check my updated solution it might be a little more simple.